# Antd Customise Theme

Tags: css, reactjs, less, antd

I am trying to customise the styling of AntD variables in my react app.

I have followed these [Advanced Guide](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) instructions and produces a config-overrides.js file with:

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');


   module.exports = override(
     fixBabelImports('import', {
       libraryName: 'antd',
       libraryDirectory: 'es',
       style: true,
    }),
    addLessLoader({
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: { 
          '@primary-color': '#bf1650', 
          '@link-color': '#1890ff',
          '@success-color': '#52c41a',
          '@warning-color': '#faad14',
          '@error-color': '#f5222d', 
          '@font-size-base': '14px', 
          '@heading-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)', 
          '@text-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)', 
          '@text-color-secondary': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .45)', 
          '@disabled-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)', 
          '@border-radius-base': '4px',
          '@border-color-base': '#d9d9d9',
          '@box-shadow-base': '0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)'
        },

        }),
  );
```

I have also seen [this instruction sheet](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) from antd - which requires changes to webpack.config.js. I don't currently have that file (and making one is not an instruction from the page I referenced above).

I changed the primary color in the above vars to red to check if it works. I don't get any errors in the console, but the primary color is still blue.

Are there any other steps required to customise the styling?

Answer (score 0):

The example from the [Advanced Guides](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides) chapter [Customize-Theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Customize-Theme) in the `antd` docs worked fine for me.

I done the following minor steps:

1. Seed a demo app

```
    yarn create react-app antd-demo
    cd antd-demo
```

2. Add `antd` dependency

```
    yarn add antd
```

3. Add [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) & craco-less

```
   yarn add @craco/craco
   yarn add craco-less
```

4. Add custom config craco

```
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' },
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

5. Rename `src/App.css` to `src/App.less`  and add `antd` less import at the top

```
   @import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

6. Adapt `src/App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import './App.less';

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

---

Some other examples can be found in the chapter [customize-theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) too, like using in a [customized webpack config](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-webpack).